# MySQL -- unique and distinct values not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to grab emails from all of our DB tables for a script I am running on my web server. Unfortunately, there are some duplicate emails in some of the tables. This should be a simple solution, with SELECT DISTINCT, INSERT IGNORE, etc, but nothing seems to be working.

This is my current query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `all_emails` (
     id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
     ip_address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     UNIQUE INDEX(email)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO `all_emails` (email, ip_address)  
SELECT email,IP_address
  FROM `table_1_emails`
 WHERE unsubscribed_at IS NULL;

INSERT IGNORE INTO `all_emails` (email, ip_address)  
SELECT email,ip_address
  FROM `table_2_emails`
 WHERE unsubscribed_at IS NULL;

INSERT IGNORE INTO all_emails (email, ip_address)  
SELECT email,ip_address
  FROM `table_3_emails`;

INSERT IGNORE INTO `all_emails` (email, ip_address)  
SELECT email,ip_address
  FROM `table_4_emails`;

SELECT DISTINCT email, ip_address, id FROM `all_emails`;
```

This still yields duplicate emails.

Comment: For `INSERT IGNORE` to work as you intend, you would first need a unique key that prevented the duplicates.

Comment: Create a unique index on `email, ip_address, id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, to prevent duplicate content, probably a unique index on just `email` and `ip_address`?

Comment: @MarcusAdams I added a unique index to email in the temporary table. I'm fine with duplicate IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UNION` to remove the duplicates in a single `INSERT`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `all_emails` (email, ip_address)  
SELECT email,IP_address
  FROM `table_1_emails`
 WHERE unsubscribed_at IS NULL
UNION
SELECT email,ip_address
  FROM `table_2_emails`
 WHERE unsubscribed_at IS NULL
UNION
SELECT email,ip_address
  FROM `table_3_emails`
UNION
SELECT email,ip_address
  FROM `table_4_emails`;
```

Comment: Getting the same results as with my SQL query.

Comment: @user3191820 Then you need to trim your the columns for trailing/leading spaces. Do all tables use the same character set?

Comment: I'm using TRIM(email) now in the SELECT statements. I also checked the tables--they're all using UTF8. One had TINYTEXT instead of VARCHAR(80), so I switched it over to VARCHAR(80). Still no luck though.